# Add groups to column header to csv file while exporting

Tags: php, export-to-csv

[image: Check this image]

As seen in my image, I want **column header with groups** in the CSV file when I export it. Now my code works without groups of header.

Here is my exported file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CSV does not support grouping columns at all.
You need to export in Excel or something like that.

Read the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180